# Fedora docker.io seems to not support btrfs

Tags: docker, btrfs

I've mounted a btrfs filesystem on /var/lib/docker, and added "-s btrfs" to /etc/sysconfig/docker.  Whenever I try to start docker the logs produce the following message:

driver not supported
[8d0e189f] -job initserver() = ERR (1)

Anyone out there with experience using btrfs with docker on a rhel/centos/fedora system.  Also, Docker was installed using the epel docker-io.rpm.

docker-io-1.0.0-6.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 2):

It does not work currently. You need to disable SELinux support for docker.
[See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7952](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7952)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference,  as the answer can become invalid if the linked page changes.